# WorkBookPath property is not available in UiPath Studio

Tags: excel, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I am working on one project in UiPath Studio. I am not able to find WorkbookPath option in Read Range activity. Is there any other option, from where I can browse my XLSX file in Read Range activity. Please check attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Read Range` activity must be within the `Excel Application Scope` (see the red message on the right upper side).

So simply delete both activities above the scope and use the existing `Read Range` on the bottom of your image.

Before that, select the `Excel Application Scope` and set the parameter `Workbook path` to your Excel file.

Now the `Read Range` works properly.

And if you need 2 different Excel files, just create another scope for that one.